# What's Wrong With My JavaScript Slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I've been building a slideshow with JavaScript, and I can't seem to get it to work.  I think part of the issue might be my referencing of an external .js file...I'm not sure if I am doing that properly with href.  However, I've tried putting the script in the head on my HTML page and using the `href:ecoquiet.html` instead, but that didn't work either.

My HTML:

```
<img class=lawnslide src="lawn.jpg" name="slideshow">
     <table>
          <tr>
               <td align=left><a href=ecoquiet.js onclick="return change_image(-1)">Previous</a></td>
               <td align=right><a href="ecoquiet:change_image(1)">Next</a></td>
               <td align=right><a href="ecoquiet:auto()">Auto</a></td>
           </tr>
     </table>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function change_image (num) {

var image = new Array("lawn.jpg", "nicelawn.jpg", "eco.png");
var description = new Array("100% Organic", "Gasoline-Free", "75% Quieter");

var = Image_Number = 0;
var = Image_Length = Image.length - 1;

Image_Number = Image_Number + num;

if (Image_Number > Image_Length) {

    Image_Number = 0;        
}

if (Image_Number < 0) {

    Image_Number = Image_Length;
}

document.slideshow.src=Image[Image_Number];
document.getElementById("decription").innerHTML = description[Image_Number];

return false;

}

function auto () {

    setInterval("change_image(1)", 3000);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add an external js file ,add it to the header section

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ecoquiet.js"></script>
```

you have missed couple of things.**Better us your browsers console to identify errors**.There is no element in your html which has an id called decription.It will give an error.

```
document.getElementById("decription").innerHTML
```

and you have `=` sign after var which will give error

```
var = Image_Number = 0;
var = Image_Length = Image.length - 1;
```

there is also a typo.you confused the image array with Image

```
var = Image_Length = Image.length - 1;// should be small case letter
```

should be `image.length`.Define Image_Number variable outside on global scope unless you are wrapping it with a closure.

don't use a parameter on a function directly when calling setInterval.Rather wrap it with another function

```
function auto () {

    setInterval(function(){
       change_image(1);


    }, 3000);

}
```

don't add any external link  to the href attribute of the anchor tag.Give it a hash string as href ,so it will not redirect you to another page.

```
<td align=left><a href='#' onclick="change_image(-1);">Previous</a></td>
<td align=right><a href="#" onclick="change_image(1);">Next</a></td>
<td align=right><a href="#" onclick="auto();">Auto</a></td>
```

Here is the changes i have made to your code :

```
var  Image_Number = 0;
function change_image (num) {

var image = new Array("lawn.jpg", "nicelawn.jpg", "eco.png");
var description = new Array("100% Organic", "Gasoline-Free", "75% Quieter");


var  Image_Length = image.length - 1;
console.log(Image_Length)

Image_Number = Image_Number + num;
console.log(Image_Number);

if (Image_Number > Image_Length) {

    Image_Number = 0;        
}

if (Image_Number < 0) {

    Image_Number = Image_Length;
}

document.slideshow.src=image[Image_Number];
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description[Image_Number];

return false;

}

function auto () {

    setInterval(function(){
       change_image(1);


    }, 3000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to reference your external JS file with a script tag in the head of your document like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ecoquiet.js"></script>
</head>
```

Second, you don't need to reference the file name when calling functions from that file.

```
 <table>
      <tr>
           <td align="left"><a href="javascript:change_image(-1); return false;">Previous</a></td>
           <td align="right"><a href="javascript:change_image(1); return false;">Next</a></td>
           <td align="right"><a href="javascript:auto(); return false;">Auto</a></td>
       </tr>
 </table>
```

The `return false` will keep the links from executing a link's normal behavior (to take you somewhere else).